# The Serial Version and The Parallel Result Not Showing the same output

Tags: c, openssl, openmp

I am actually new to openmp, I have a working aes-128-cbc toy code that decrypts an hardcoded ciphertext to 12345, [this book](https://www.openmp.org//wp-content/uploads/openmp-examples-4.5.0.pdf) was recommended for me by one of the community user, I also came across this [openmp reference guide](https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/OpenMP-4.5-1115-CPP-web.pdf) and lastly I was heavily guided by one of the community user. From those books and the guide, I was trying to parallelize the serial code below

SERIAL WORKING CODE:

```
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>


int success = 0;

void handleOpenSSLErrors(void)
{
    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    abort();
}

unsigned char* decrypt(unsigned char *ciphertext, int ciphertext_len, unsigned char *key, unsigned char *iv ){

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;
    unsigned char *plaintexts;
    int len;
    int plaintext_len;

    unsigned char* plaintext = malloc(ciphertext_len);
    bzero(plaintext,ciphertext_len);

    /* Create and initialise the context */

    if(!(ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new())) handleOpenSSLErrors();

    /* Initialise the decryption operation. IMPORTANT - ensure you use a key
    * and IV size appropriate for your cipher
    * IV size for *most* modes is the same as the block size. For AES this
    * is 128 bits */

    if(1 != EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_128_cbc(), NULL, key, iv))
        handleOpenSSLErrors();


    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_key_length(ctx, EVP_MAX_KEY_LENGTH);

    /* Provide the message to be decrypted, and obtain the plaintext output.
    * EVP_DecryptUpdate can be called multiple times if necessary
    */
    if(1 != EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, plaintext, &len, ciphertext, ciphertext_len))
        handleOpenSSLErrors();

    plaintext_len = len;

    /* Finalise the decryption. Further plaintext bytes may be written at
    * this stage.
    */

    // return 1 if decryption successful, otherwise 0
    if(1 == EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(ctx, plaintext + len, &len))
        success = 1;
    plaintext_len += len;


    /* Add the null terminator */
    plaintext[plaintext_len] = 0;

    /* Clean up */
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
    //delete [] plaintext;
    return plaintext;
}


size_t calcDecodeLength(char* b64input) {
    size_t len = strlen(b64input), padding = 0;

    if (b64input[len-1] == '=' && b64input[len-2] == '=') //last two chars are =
        padding = 2;
    else if (b64input[len-1] == '=') //last char is =
        padding = 1;
    return (len*3)/4 - padding;
}

void Base64Decode( char* b64message, unsigned char** buffer, size_t* length) {


    BIO *bio, *b64;  // A BIO is an I/O strean abstraction

    int decodeLen = calcDecodeLength(b64message);
    *buffer = (unsigned char*)malloc(decodeLen + 1);
    (*buffer)[decodeLen] = '\0';

    bio = BIO_new_mem_buf(b64message, -1);
    b64 = BIO_new(BIO_f_base64());
    bio = BIO_push(b64, bio);

    //BIO_set_flags(bio, BIO_FLAGS_BASE64_NO_NL); //Do not use newlines to flush buffer
    *length = BIO_read(bio, *buffer, strlen(b64message));
    BIO_free_all(bio);
}

void initAES(const unsigned char *pass, unsigned char* salt, unsigned char* key, unsigned char* iv )
{
    //initialisatio of key and iv with 0
    bzero(key,sizeof(key));
    bzero(iv,sizeof(iv));

    EVP_BytesToKey(EVP_aes_128_cbc(), EVP_sha1(), salt, pass, strlen(pass), 1, key, iv);
}


int checkPlaintext(char* plaintext, char* result){

    int length = 10; // we just check the first then characters
    return strncmp(plaintext, result, length);

}

int main (void)
{

    // password 12345
    // it took 9 seconds to work out
    char* ciphertext_base64 = (char*) "U2FsdGVkX19q3SzS6GhhzAKgK/YhFVTkM3RLVxxZ+nM6yXdfLZtvhyRR4oGohDotiifnR1iKyitSpiBM3hng+eoFfGbtgCu3Zh9DwIhgfS5A+OTl5a4L7pRFG4yL432HsMGRC1hy1RNPSzA0U5YyWA==\n";

    char* plaintext = "This is the top seret message in parallel computing! Please keep it in a safe place.";
    char dict[] = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"; // changed

    int decryptedtext_len, ciphertext_len, dict_len;

    // cipher (binary) pointer and length
    size_t cipher_len; // size_t is sizeof(type)
    unsigned char* ciphertext;

    unsigned char salt[8];

    ERR_load_crypto_strings();

    Base64Decode(ciphertext_base64, &ciphertext, &cipher_len);

    unsigned char key[16];
    unsigned char iv[16];

    unsigned char plainpassword[] = "00000";
    unsigned char* password = &plainpassword[0];

    // retrive the slater from ciphertext (binary)
    if (strncmp((const char*)ciphertext,"Salted__",8) == 0) { // find the keyword "Salted__"

        memcpy(salt,&ciphertext[8],8);
        ciphertext += 16;
        cipher_len -= 16;

    }

    dict_len = strlen(dict);

    time_t begin = time(NULL);


    for(int i=0; i<dict_len; i++)
        for(int j=0; j<dict_len; j++)
            for(int k=0; k<dict_len; k++)
                for(int l=0; l<dict_len; l++)
                    for(int m=0; m<dict_len; m++){
                        *password = dict[i];
                        *(password+1) = dict[j];
                        *(password+2) = dict[k];
                        *(password+3) = dict[l];
                        *(password+4) = dict[m];


                        initAES(password, salt, key, iv);
                        unsigned char* result = decrypt(ciphertext, cipher_len, key, iv);

                        if (success == 1){
                            if(checkPlaintext(plaintext, result)==0){

                                printf("Password is %s\n", password);

                                time_t end = time(NULL);
                                printf("Time elpased is %ld seconds", (end - begin));

                                return 0;
                            }

                        }

                        free(result);
                    }


    // Clean up

    EVP_cleanup();
    ERR_free_strings();


    return 0;
}
```

THIS IS THE PARALLEL VERSION:

```
int main (void)
{

    // password 12345
    // it took 9 seconds to work out
    char* ciphertext_base64 = (char*) "U2FsdGVkX19q3SzS6GhhzAKgK/YhFVTkM3RLVxxZ+nM6yXdfLZtvhyRR4oGohDotiifnR1iKyitSpiBM3hng+eoFfGbtgCu3Zh9DwIhgfS5A+OTl5a4L7pRFG4yL432HsMGRC1hy1RNPSzA0U5YyWA==\n";

    char* plaintext = "This is the top seret message in parallel computing! Please keep it in a safe place.";
    char dict[] = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"; // changed

    int decryptedtext_len, ciphertext_len, dict_len;

    // cipher (binary) pointer and length
    size_t cipher_len; // size_t is sizeof(type)
    unsigned char* ciphertext;

    unsigned char salt[8];

    ERR_load_crypto_strings();

    Base64Decode(ciphertext_base64, &ciphertext, &cipher_len);

    unsigned char key[16];
    unsigned char iv[16];

    omp_set_num_threads(NUM_THREADS);

    double begin = omp_get_wtime();

    
    // retrive the slater from ciphertext (binary)
    if (strncmp((const char*)ciphertext,"Salted__",8) == 0)
    { // find the keyword "Salted__"

        memcpy(salt,&ciphertext[8],8);
        ciphertext += 16;
        cipher_len -= 16;

    }

    dict_len = strlen(dict);

    #pragma omp parallel for shared (key, iv)

    for (int i=0; i<dict_len; i++) 
    {
     unsigned char password[5] = {i};

        for(int j=0; j<dict_len; j++)
        {
         password[1] = dict[j];
            for(int k=0; k<dict_len; k++)
            {
                password[2] = dict[k];
                for(int l=0; l<dict_len; l++)
                {
                  password[3] = dict[l];
                    for(int m=0; m<dict_len; m++)
                    {
                      password[4] = dict[m];
                        {
                            *password = dict[i];
                            *(password+1) = dict[j];
                            *(password+2) = dict[k];
                            *(password+3) = dict[l];
                            *(password+4) = dict[m];


                            initAES(password, salt, key, iv);
                            unsigned char* result = decrypt(ciphertext, cipher_len, key, iv);

                                #pragma omp if(checkPlaintext(plaintext, result)==0)
                                {
                                    
                                    printf("\nPassword is %s\n\n", password);
                                    success == 1;
                                    strcpy(result,password); // Copy thread-private copy to shared variable
                                    time_t end = time(NULL);
                                    printf("\nTime elpased is %ld seconds\n", (end - begin));

                                    exit(0);

                                }

                            free(result);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
          #pragma omp cancellation point for
        }
    }

// Clean up
EVP_cleanup();
ERR_free_strings();
return 0;
}
```

Should bring my expected password, but when I run the code it does not output the expected [image: outcome]. Kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

You have only one buffer for the trial password (`plainpassword`), and all of the threads in your `parallel for` are trying to use it at the same time (via pointer `password`).  There are massive data races here, and the resulting behavior is undefined.

One solution would be to declare the buffer *inside* the parallel loop instead of outside, as variables local to a parallel region are automatically private -- each thread will have its own.

```
    #pragma omp parallel for shared (key, iv)
    for (int i=0; i<dict_len; i++) {
        unsigned char password[5] = { i };

        for (int j=0; j<dict_len; j++) {
            password[1] = dict[j];

            for (int k=0; k<dict_len; k++) {
                password[2] = dict[k];

                for (int l=0; l<dict_len; l++) {
                    password[3] = dict[l];

                    for (int m=0; m<dict_len; m++) {
                        password[4] = dict[m];

                        // ...

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Note also that

- there is no apparent benefit in your original code to having both `plainpassword` and `password`.  The above uses just an array, not a separate pointer as well, and it chooses the name "`password`" for that.
- `*(x + y)`, where `x` and `y` are primaries, means exactly the same thing as `x[y]` (and `y[x]`).  The subscript form is easier to read, and that almost always makes it stylistically better.

**Update:**

I observe also that this code from the parallel version does not make sense, especially as compared to the serial code:

> ```
>     #pragma omp parallel if (strncmp((const char*)ciphertext,"Salted__",8) == 0) shared(ciphertext, plaintext, ciphertext_base64) private(salt)
>     { // find the keyword "Salted__"
>
>         memcpy(salt,&ciphertext[8],8);
>         ciphertext += 16;
>         cipher_len -= 16;
>
>     }
> ```

The original code executes the `if` statement once per run, and its body at most once per run, so if the parallel version executes the body multiple times, and it has side effects (which it does), then the result of the program will be different.  The original code should be restored for this part.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your guide, I have adjusted the parallel code trying to follow your points(although I made the password private instead of the declaration inside the for loop since using that is showing me like undeclared variable error). I commented the plainpassword, then work on the other conditions. The obvious diffrence now is that the code exits after running(unlike before that I have to manually close the compiler). Kindly help me look into what I am doing wrong again.

Comment: Hello Mr John, when I do exactly as you guided me, I keep seeing the error that starts with what is pasted below. Please kindly guide me more sir: `In function 'main':
anotherparallel.c:163:9: error: expected expression before 'unsigned'
  163 |         unsigned char password[5] = { i };
      |         ^~~~~~~~
anotherparallel.c:165:13: error: 'password' undeclared (first use in this function)
  165 |             password[1] = dict[j];`

Comment: @AdeoluTemitopeOlofintuyi, more than likely, the compile error you report is related to the lack of braces around some of your loop bodies.  I copied that feature of your original code, and did not pay enough attention to recognize the issue.  I have since corrected the code in this answer.  This is, by the way, a prime example of why stylistically, you should *always* use braces around the bodies of `for`, `do`, and `while` loops, and of `if` and `else` statements, even when the braces enclose only one statement.

Comment: Wow!! Thanks a lot sir, for your quick response and guide, I will test the new guide and will get back to you asap. Thanks a lot once again.

Comment: Hello Mr John, I have updated the code(I carefully followed your guide sir), but I didn't see any result to even confirm if the password match with the serial version. Kindly look into this sir. Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: @AdeoluTemitopeOlofintuyi, I have added comments about another, separate issue with your parallel code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your review sir, even when the original code is restored,  it still doesn't generate any output exactly the same problem like before.

Comment: @AdeoluTemitopeOlofintuyi, it looks like you also have a data race involving global variable `success`, though you do not actually present that in the parallel version.  Instead of using a global variable to convey that datum back to its caller, function `decrypt()` should convey it via its return value or an out argument.  For example, it might return a null pointer in the case of decryption failure, and the caller could test whether the return value is null to determine whether decryption succeeded.

Comment: Sincerely speaking sir, I really don't know how to fix this issue you pointed out, kindly help sir.

Comment: @AdeoluTemitopeOlofintuyi, I already gave you a suggestion for a way to fix the global-variable problem, but here's a more general prescription: get rid of the global `success` variable.  Devise a mechanism to convey decryption success or failure that does not depend on global variables.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your guide and time, I will work on it and give you feedback when I'm done sir.

Comment: I just which you could help me by writing the working solution, with this I would have been able to read the code and learn the theoretical part very well since there's practical one available. Trying to change the global variables to local is affecting `decrypt` function and I'm not getting it. I've been fully on this today for over 12 hours straight.  I still appreciate your time and the previously pointed out issues. I don't know that parallel computing could be this difficult.

Comment: Hello sir, kindly take a look at my code again, it is outputting now, but not my expectation.

Comment: @AdeoluTemitopeOlofintuyi, this makes no sense: `#pragma omp if(checkPlaintext(plaintext, result)==0)`.  OpenMP does not have an `if` directive (though it does have `if` *clauses* that can qualify certain directives).  Your compiler ought to be warning you about that.  In any event, I don't see what you think that would gain you over an ordinary C `if` statement.  I also don't see what purpose this is supposed to serve: "`strcpy(result,password)`", though I doubt it is affecting your output.

Comment: wow!! I truly appreciate your time, the problem is that, I don't actually know how to make the program know the expected output and tgen terminate if found, so I thought the, `if` clause works similar to the serial version. The purpose of `strcpy`(from my understanding ), is to copy the result and password to other threads so that termination can occur.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, I am now able to parallelize the code using openmp. I really appreciate sir.